# TradingView [PINE]: Can I change study overlay dynamically via the settings?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

When defining a [TradingView study](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_study), we have the following supported settings

```
study(title, shorttitle, overlay, format, precision, scale, max_bars_back, max_lines_count, max_labels_count, resolution, resolution_gaps, max_boxes_count) → void
```

where I am interested into the `overlay` property

```
overlay (const bool) - default is false.
- if true, the study will be added as an overlay for the main series. 
- if false, it would be added on a separate chart pane.
```

What I am interested into is, can this property be set dynamically?

For example, in the indicator settings, I can add an input field from where the user should be able to choose either the current indicator to be shown in the main series overlay or either to be shown in a separate chart pane.

```
study_overlay = input(defval = "true", title = "Study Overlay", options = ["true", "false"])
```

When user is going to change the selected options there, the indicator should change the pane that is using, based on the selected option.

Is this feasible? I tried something like

```
study_overlay_string = input(defval = "true", title = "Study Overlay", options = ["true", "false"])
study_overlay_bool = true
if study_overlay_string == "false"
    study_overlay_bool = false
study("My Script", overlay = study_overlay_bool)
```

This study can be added to the chart, but when changing the setting, nothing happens!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `overlay` argument is of the `const bool` type so you cannot use an input to pass a value to it. All input-based variables have an `input` type form; input is more narrow than `const` and cannot be converted into `const`.

Your script works because you use `=` instead of `:=` in your `if`-block. Instead of assigning a value to the global scope `study_overlay_bool` variable, you create a separate local scope variable with the same name (note the compiler warning that should appear in the console). If you use `:=` there instead, you'll get the expected type error.